# How to pass a DTO to Edit POST Action from a form in Edit view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am adding CRUD user management to my ASP.NET MVC application. I'm using Identity. I'm using a DTO to work with the ApplicationUser properties and AutoMapper to map the UserDto to ApplicationUser and vice-versa.
When I try to pass the DTO to the Edit/POST action, back from the form (from the View), all the properties of the DTO are null except for Id

I.e. when posting the form and debugging the application, all the properties of the DTO passed as argument to the Edit action are null, except for Id which is correct.

Can I pass the DTO back to the controller and how do I do that?

**UserDTO.cs**

```
public class UserDto
{
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "E-mail Confirmed")]
    public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Lockout Enddate")]
    public DateTime? LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Lockout Enabled")]
    public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Access Failed Count")]
    public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }

}
```

The DTO is included in the ViewModel which is passed to the View. I use the same ViewModel to view the User's details and it works fine:

**UserDetailsViewModel.cs**

```
public class UserDetailsViewModel
{        
    public UserDto User { get; set; }
    public UserRolesViewModel UserRolesViewModel { get; set; }

    public UserDetailsViewModel(UserDto user)
    {
        User = user;
        UserRolesViewModel = new UserRolesViewModel(user.Id);
    }
}
```

**Users/Edit.cshtml**

```html
@model MyApp.ViewModels.UserDetailsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = Model.User.FirstName + " " + Model.User.Surname;
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">

            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.User.Id)

            <div class="form-horizontal">

                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "has-error" })

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control boxed" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.FirstName, "", new { @class = "has-error" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Surname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.Surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control boxed" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.Surname, "", new { @class = "has-error" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control boxed" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.Email, "", new { @class = "has-error" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.EmailConfirmed, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.EmailConfirmed, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "checkbox" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.EmailConfirmed, "", new { @class = "has-error" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.LockoutEndDateUtc, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.LockoutEndDateUtc, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control boxed" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.LockoutEndDateUtc, "", new { @class = "has-error" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.LockoutEnabled, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.LockoutEnabled)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.LockoutEnabled, "", new { @class = "has-error" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.AccessFailedCount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.AccessFailedCount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control boxed" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.AccessFailedCount, "", new { @class = "has-error" })
                </div>

            </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            }

            <div>
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="user-roles" class="card" data-user-id="@Model.User.Id">
        @Html.Partial("_UserRoles", Model.UserRolesViewModel)
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts-user-roles")
}
```

And finally, the current implementation of the Edit action. The ModelState is always invalid because of the null values of the userDto:

**UsersController.cs**

```
// POST: Users/Edit/jhdjdkjdh-asuhhahf
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(UserDto userDto)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var applicationUser = _context.Users.Find(userDto.Id);
        applicationUser.FirstName = userDto.FirstName;
        applicationUser.Surname = userDto.Surname;
        applicationUser.Email = userDto.Email;
        applicationUser.EmailConfirmed = userDto.EmailConfirmed;
        applicationUser.LockoutEndDateUtc = userDto.LockoutEndDateUtc;
        applicationUser.LockoutEnabled = userDto.LockoutEnabled;
        applicationUser.AccessFailedCount = userDto.AccessFailedCount;
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return View(new UserDetailsViewModel(userDto));
    }

    return View("Details", new UserDetailsViewModel(userDto));
}
```

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but it shows the dto working in mvc : https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=how+to+use+data+transfer+object%3f&docid=607998179969729255&mid=85179D1E2AFAE3ED657085179D1E2AFAE3ED6570&view=detail&FORM=VIREHT

Comment: What happens if in your Edit method in the controller you change the parameter to be of type UserDetailsViewModel, does the model binding work then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the view, your model is `MyApp.ViewModels.UserDetailsViewModel`, so when you submit the form, it will send UserDetailsViewModel model to action. But Edit action is expecting UserDTO model, so binding will not work due to model mismatch. You should have UserDetailsViewModel as input parameter to Edit action and read the UserDto from that, something like below (changed 2 lines of Edit action).

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(UserDetailsViewModel model) // Changed the input parmater
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var userDto = model.User; // read the user from view model
        var applicationUser = _context.Users.Find(userDto.Id);
        applicationUser.FirstName = userDto.FirstName;
        applicationUser.Surname = userDto.Surname;
        applicationUser.Email = userDto.Email;
        applicationUser.EmailConfirmed = userDto.EmailConfirmed;
        applicationUser.LockoutEndDateUtc = userDto.LockoutEndDateUtc;
        applicationUser.LockoutEnabled = userDto.LockoutEnabled;
        applicationUser.AccessFailedCount = userDto.AccessFailedCount;
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return View(new UserDetailsViewModel(userDto));
    }

    return View("Details", new UserDetailsViewModel(userDto));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the gist of it and I understand now that the action expects the same model as the one passed to the view. I couldn't use the viewmodel without refactoring though, because it requires id as parameter and I got an exception. So I went with the solution proposed by Mike Atkisson.

Comment: FWIW, this was the first solution I thought of and saw it posted here after I had completed my answer.  It got an upvote from me.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET is unable to properly *de-serialize* `UserDto` because the HTTP request variables don't match the properties found in the UserDto class.  This is most likely happening because the request values are being labelled as, for example, `User.FirstName` versus just `FirstName` when your cshtml page is converted to HTML.  The heart of the issue is that you're associating your `UserDetailViewModel` as the view's Model, while wanting to de-serialize an instance of the flatter `UserDto` class.

### Emitted HTML

Let's take a closer look.  For starters, here's a snippet from your form.

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control boxed" } })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.Email, "", new { @class = "has-error"})
</div>
```

which gets rendered into this markup

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="User_Email">Email</label>
  <input class="form-control boxed text-box single-line" id="User_Email" name="User.Email" type="text" value="">
  <span class="field-validation-valid has-error" data-valmsg-for="User.Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

Notice in the markup above the input field has the `name="User.Email"` attribute making `User.Email` the key of the HTTP POST request parameter.  We can see this a bit more closely looking at the web developer tools in a modern browser.  I'm using Chrome here.

[image]

### Server-side Troubleshooting

One of the things I like to do when de-serialization issues like this occur is to check the request parameters on the server side.  This can be done pretty easily by setting a breakpoint in the Controller Action of interest and pressing F5 in Visual Studio.  Once you're in an active debug session inspect the `Request.Params.AllKeys` variable inside of a watch window.

[image]

In your case this is probably something like `User.Email`.  Hence, ASP.NET won't be able to properly convert your request into a UserDto because UserDto contains a plain `Email` property rather than a `User.Email` property.

### Solutions

There are several ways to solve this particular de-serialization mismatch.  Probably the easiest of which is to simply use your `UserDetailViewModel` as the argument of the controller which handles the HTTP Post for your request.

Another solution might be to associate the flat UserDto with your `Edit.cshtml` view.

Still another solution is to keep everything the same as you have it now, but to manually specify the name attribute of the `@Html.EditorFor()` method as shown below.  This may not work for you depending on the version of ASP.NET your app is targetting.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { Name = "email", @class = "form-control boxed" } })
```

Also, note the `Name` attribute in the syntax above *is* case sensitive.

Comment: Glad to help.  I appreciate the time you took to post your question with clarity.